# Grails Tomcat blank page

Tags: grails, tomcat7, gsp

Hi I have deployed my grails webapp and I thought all was fine but it seems any GSP page that has not been requested from within the app just displays a black page on my deployed tomcat 7.

I can log in and use 90% of the functionality but not that page.

```
  http:somewebsite.co.uk/app/invite/index
```

from within the webapp i can get to

```
 http:somewebsite.co.uk/app/invite/index
```

but i cannot access this but just entering the URL within the browser.

This does however work in my IDE.

at the top of the controller i have.

```
 static allowedMethods = [index: 'GET']
```

and i do not need to be logged in to access.

as anyone had and fixed this problem?

I have not preformed numerous test and the problem is something to do with this code:

```
  def index() {
            def em   =   params.email
    if (em){

    println("params.email : " + em)
    if (User.findByEmail(em)){

        redirect controller:"public", action:"index"

      }
    }
      [email: em]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the index.gsp page, i use layouts and the name was set to oneBlock, instead of oneblock.